# delete from beginning of file to nth occurrence of pattern

Tags: text-processing

Looking for command line tool (awk, sed, etc.) command to omit lines from the beginning of a file to the nth occurrence of a pattern.  Stated another way, print only from the nth occurrence of pattern to end of file.  Assume one match per line; line does not necessarily begin with pattern.

e.g. omit from beginning of file to second `foo` in the following:

```
something
abc foo1
maybe something else
foo2 -this line and anything before is gone- 
maybe not
foo3
something
```

Desired result:

```
maybe not
foo3
something
```

Bonus points for including/excluding the line with the nth occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To *exclude* the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the pattern

```
awk -v 'n=3' 'NR == 1, /pattern/ && !--n {next}; 1'
```

(replace `3` with the number of occurrences you want (2 in your case), and `pattern` with your actual pattern (`foo` in your case)).

Example:

```
$ seq 30 | awk -v 'n=3' 'NR == 1, /6/ && !--n {next}; 1'
27
28
29
30
```

### To *include* the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the pattern

```
awk -v 'n=3' '/pattern/ && !--n, 0'
```

Example:

```
$ seq 30 | awk -v 'n=3' '/6/ && !--n, 0'
26
27
28
29
30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% perl -ne 'BEGIN{$NTH=2;$p=0} print if $p; /foo/ && $NTH--; $p=1 if !$NTH' input
maybe not
foo3
something
```

Where `NTH` is how many times, and then you need a to-print flag; decrement `NTH` on match and enable printing if `NTH` decremented enough. **Move `print` to end to catch the ultimate desired `foo`.**

Comment: I'm not familiar with perl. Couldn't make it capture the second foo.  Can you give the command for that?